# Проверить программно, поддерживает ОС и провайдер IPv6/Teredo/ISATAP

Tags: c++, qt, сеть, windows-10, ipv6

Пишу приложение на C++ Qt5.7 (Windows 10 x64, MinGW), которое должно проверять, поддерживает ли IPv6/Teredo/ISATAP:

1. Операционная система ПК, на котором этот софт установлен,
2. Роутер, за которым находится этот ПК,
3. Провайдер Интернета, дающий ему выход во внешку.

Интересует преимущественно, как реализовать это под Windows. Как включить такую поддержку на уровне ОС, юзая регистр Windows и др. его системные компоненты? Покажите пример кода, делающего это.

Каким сетевым запросом и в каком формате проверить, поддерживается ли IPv6 провайдером? Покажите пример кода, посылающего такой запрос и разбирающего пришедший ответ от роутера/сервера провайдера.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40417881/1068283

Comment: @MichaelHampton, А зачем вы мне привели ссылку на топик, где **нет** ответа _ни на один из трёх_ вопросов, которые у меня здесь написаны??